# batch file to assign a variable and compare with a string

Tags: batch-file

I would like to know how I could achieve this, I tried few times with no luck.. I get a syntax error

I need to write a batch file to read the first line of a text, assign to a variable and then compare with a string.

bool.txt:

```
Hello
```

test.bat:

```
set  Variable =< C:\bool.txt
if "%Variable%"=="Hello"
echo I am here
```

Thanks in advance
SR

Answer (score 5):

see `help for` and `help set` and then try this

```
 for /f %%a in (bool.txt) do (
     if "%%a"="Hello" echo I am here
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space after the variable name, therefore you're not setting the variable `%Variable%` but `%Variable %`.

Use

```
set /p Variable=< bool.txt
```

instead.